# C++: find a string in an array of sub-string efficiently

Tags: c++, arrays, string, stl

I've got an array of string prefixes: `std::vector<std::string> haystack = {"/bin/", "/usr/bin/", "/usr/local/bin/"}`.

Is there an efficient way to find that a `std::string needle = "/bin/echo"` starts with a sub-string from `haystack`, using standard C++ library?

If I would need to find the exact match, I could use `std::set<std::string>`, which would perform an efficient binary search, however I need to match only the first part of the string, so currently I'm doing it using a simple loop:

```
for (auto it = haystack.begin(); it != haystack.end(); it++) {
    if (needle.compare(0, it->size(), *it) == 0) {
        return true; // Found it
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Define _efficient_ please. To shorten the code there's `std::find_if()`.

Comment: Faster than iterating through the whole `haystack` array, which would be `O(n)`. `find_if` will perform the exact same loop with `O(n)` speed.

Comment: Divide and conquer. But even that can't guarantee being faster than O(n).

Comment: Be more precise about search string and searched text. Do you want to test any prefix for each string. Do all prefix are directory ending with /. Do you want to find file at any level under prefix directories or only immediate child. That kind of details would help finding the most efficient way to do it. It would also depends on the data size...

Comment: Are the prefixes sorted? What do you mean by "prefix": full match or partial match? Would "/bin/foo/echo" match "/bin/"? Can prefix contain something like "/usr/lib" and match "/usr/lib64/baz"?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question since those answers only cover half the question (if at all).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Feel free to vote for reopening.

Comment: Sounds like you are implementing some sort of user-initiated auto-completion. In that case, do you have a reason to make anything *"more efficient"*? Did profiling indicate a bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, in my example "/bin/foo/echo" would match "/bin/". I don't need to go through the rest of the array, if one match is found.

Comment: @pelya There's `break;`??

Comment: Yes, I've updated my code example to reflect that.

Comment: One really efficient algorithm would be a trie structure, used for autocompletion, modified to check for a complete string match instead of a partial results, the efficiency would be `O(needle.size())` instead of `O(haystack.size() * needle.size())`. Unfortunately the trie is not a part of C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort `hasystack` by descending string length.
2. Compare prefixes no longer than `needle` in that order; do it right to left. E. g. if `prefix` is 5 characters long, compare `prefix[4]` to `needle[4]`, then `prefix[3]` to `needle[3]` and so on.

This way you will instantly discard many non-matches. As a bonus, you will find the longest match first (might just be what you want).

Comment: Why sort the haystack? That turns this into an `O(n log n)` operation in the haystack's size. It's `O(n)` otherwise.

Comment: @Richard: this isn't strictly necessary. Assuming it is not required to find the longest matches first, sorting may or may not be beneficial depending on the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

The one "optimization" I'd add is that if you use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) it will short-circuit upon finding the first substring match

```
auto found = std::any_of(begin(haystack),
                         end(haystack),
                         [&needle](std::string const& sub)
                         { 
                             return needle.compare(0, sub.size(), sub) == 0;
                         });
```

Otherwise if you want to find *which* substring matched, you could use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), which will also short-circuit upon finding the first match.

```
auto match = std::find_if(begin(haystack),
                          end(haystack),
                          [&needle](std::string const& sub)
                          { 
                              return needle.compare(0, sub.size(), sub) == 0;
                          });
```

Comment: I only need to find the first match in the array, I've updated my code example.